# Getting Error When Open Sharepoint Central Admin After Windows Updates

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, patching

Hello Group members,
                     "Management studio failed to open" and unable to open any of the sites

Today I stopped the windows updates.And removing the updates till then my SP works good,When I got message to restart after some uninstall updates and open the sites not able to open.And when i open the Sql Server r2 2008 Showing message as "Management studio failed to open"

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bit of a mess.  First step would be to finalize any windows updates that are in the process of being applied.  After that is done, make sure that you do a full reboot since it is likely that the patching will not be finalized yet.

Next, ensure that the services are started.  Most likely the SQL services are not starting which is preventing you from connecting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin.microsoft_com in your web browser to open the Office 365 admin center. Then in the navigation pane or in the list of all admin centers, click SharePoint to open a SharePoint admin center.

Hope You Find This Useful,
Peter